# Sound profiles missing for Logitech G533 Wireless Headset on Ubuntu 20

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, logitech, headset, pavucontrol

I have the following setup:

- Thinkpad Laptop with Ubuntu 20
- PC with Ubuntu 20
- KVM Switch connected to PC and Laptop
- Logitech G533 wireless Headset connected to the KVM switch

On my PC the headset is working without problems. But on my laptop not. At first I could not select the headset as input and as output on the same time. If I choosed one of it, the other one was switching. Then I installed `pavucontrol` and checked the problem. After I boot my laptop there are only 5 profiles in the pavucontrol configuration tab for my headset:

- Mono Input
- Multichannel Input
- Analog Stereo Output
- Digital Stereo Output
- Off

On my PC there are also these profiles:

- Analog Stereo Output + Multichannel Input
- Analog Stereo Output + Mono Input
- Digital Stereo Output + Multichannel Input
- Digital Stereo Output + Mono Input

These are missing on my laptop directly after boot. I think thats the reason why I can't select the headset as input and output at the same time. Only sometimes, when I unplug the switch from my laptop and plug it in again, this profiles appear and I can select them and then I can select the headset as input and output at the same time. But when I reboot then, they are missing again.

Does anyone have an idea how I can enable this profiles permanent?